# How to remove all files except the ones that matches a pattern along several number of directories

Tags: linux, bash, rm, extglob

lets say I have a my_dirs/ directory, insdie that directory I have several parallel subdirectories which has several files and I want to delete all of them except the ones that have the substring '.regions'

this is my parent directory content:
[image]

this is what I tried:

```
shopt -s extglob

rm -r !(./**/*.regions*)
```

but I got an error message: cannot be deleted «! (./**/*. region *) »: The file or directory does not exist.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, always be careful when deleting multiple files.
The command to achieve what you want would be:

```sh
find my_dirs -type f ! -name "*.regions*" -delete
```

**"-delete" must be last, otherwise it will delete *everything* it finds**

This will explore all subdirectories in `my_dirs`, find the files (`-type f`) that not (`!`) contain ".regions" (`"*.regions*"`) on their name, and delete (`-delete`) them.

I recommend running this first: `find my_dirs -type f ! -name "*.regions*"`,
so it won't delete anything and you can check the files are correct.

Edit: Added `-type f` so it only targets files per Philippe's suggestion.

Comment: You may want to add `-type f`. Otherwise it will try to delete directories.

Comment: `! -name '?*.regions?*'` will not exclude, say, `foo.regions`. What is the point of question marks?